# Make the moon's 3D gif

Tags: graphics3d, image-processing, animation

How do I make the following [gif](https://assets.ello.co/uploads/asset/attachment/3784206/ello-optimized-ec9a49bd.gif)

[image]

I tried:

```
moon = Import[
 "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Full_Moon_as_Seen_From_Denmark.jpg"];

{r, g, b} = ColorSeparate[ImageResize[moon, 200]] 


ListPlot3D[ImageData[r, DataReversed -> True], Mesh -> False, 
ColorFunction -> "GrayTones", Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

but..

[image]

Comment: What is the "but.."? Are you after the animation part?

Comment: @YvesKlett "but.." this is a ugly image, my method doesn't work. see [here ](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7v77pdyv4n82ajk/333.PNG?dl=0) diference

Comment: vito - do you just browse [this site](https://www.reddit.com/r/gonwild/) for images?

Comment: It would be useful to state all your requirements / gripes with your solution in the question.

Comment: Sorry for the edit but I believe this is about the Moon, not any moon, right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is an approach based on direct construction of `Image3D` from `ImageData`. The basic idea is taken from the subsection "Volume Creation" of the section "Scope" on the Documentation page for `Image3D`, some other ideas are from the [answer by Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/113219/280):

```
moon = Import[
 "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Full_Moon_as_Seen_From_Denmark.jpg"];

moonGray = ImageResize[ImageCrop@ColorConvert[moon, "Grayscale"], Scaled@.5];

height = 70;
data = ImageData[moonGray]^3;
data3D = Reverse@Table[data UnitStep[height data - k], {k, height}];

im = Image3D[data3D, ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[Surd[#, 3], Sign[#]] &), 
  SphericalRegion -> True, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}, Background -> Black, 
  ImageSize -> 500];

pics = Table[
   Rasterize[Image3D[im, ViewPoint -> 1000 {0, -Sin[i], 1}], "Image"], 
    {i, .1, Pi, Pi/24.}];

Export["moon.gif", pics, "GIF", 
 "DisplayDurations" -> Append[ConstantArray[1/15., Length[pics] - 1], 1]]
```

[image: gif]

---

### UPDATE

With `RotationAction -> "Clip"` (instead of `SphericalRegion -> True`) and fixed `ImageSize -> {500, 512}` we can get rid of the margins:

```
im = Image3D[data3D, ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[Surd[#, 3], Sign[#]] &), 
  RotationAction -> "Clip", ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}, Background -> Black, 
  ImageSize -> {500, 512}]

pics = Table[
   Rasterize[Image3D[im, ViewPoint -> 1000 {0, -Sin[i], 1}], "Image"], {i, .1, Pi, 
    Pi/24.}];

Export["moon.gif", pics, "GIF", 
 "DisplayDurations" -> Append[ConstantArray[1/15., Length[pics] - 1], 1]]
```

[image: gif]

(I have reduced the number of colors in the final GIF to 50 using `gifsicle` in order to fit the 2Mb file size limit).

Answer (score 14):

```
moon = Import[
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Full_Moon_as_\
Seen_From_Denmark.jpg"]
```

Here are two ways to get something like that:

- with `Texture` or
- with `ColorFunction`

---

### `Texture`:

```
pic = ImageCrop @ ImageResize[ColorConvert[moon, "Grayscale"], Scaled@.3]
```

Worse quality than is possible with this image but I had to make it smaller due to the lack of time :P. Feel free to change rescaling factor.

```
texture = ImageCrop @ ColorConvert[moon, "Grayscale"];

ListPlot3D[ImageData[pic, DataReversed -> True]^3,
 Mesh             -> None,
 PlotStyle        -> Texture[texture],     
 Lighting         -> {{"Ambient",  White}},
 ViewPoint        -> 1000 {0, -.001, 1},
 ImageSize        -> 800,
 PlotRangePadding -> {50, 50, 0},
 RotationAction   -> "Clip",
 Boxed            -> False,
 Axes             -> False,
 Background       -> Black,
 PlotRange        -> All,
 ViewVertical     -> {0, 1, 0}
]
```

It is even responsible enough to play with:

[image]

---

### `ColorFunction`

You need to:

- change the `ColorFunction` so it respects original color space, then it will look naturally. Also, make the `Lighting` less interfering: `Lighting -> {{"Directional", White, {0, 0, 1000}}}`
- transform values of pixels, as seen on linked example those peaks are way bigger that they should be comparing to other areas on the Moon: `ImageData[...]^7`
- use the inverse transformation for `ColorFunction` so the coloring doesn't care about what you've done with values:  `ColorFunction -> (Blend[..., Surd[#3, 7]] &)`

---

```
pic = ImageResize[ColorConvert[moon, "Grayscale"], Scaled@.2];

pics = Table[
   x = 1000 {0, Sin[i], 1};
   
   Rasterize @ ListPlot3D[
     ImageData[pic, DataReversed -> True]^7, 
     Mesh            -> None, 
     ColorFunction   -> (Blend[{Black, White}, Surd[#3, 7]] &), 
     Lighting        -> {{"Directional", White, {0, 0, 1000}}}, 
     ViewPoint       -> x, 
     Boxed           -> False, 
     Axes            -> False, 
     Background      -> Black, 
     SphericalRegion -> True, 
     PlotRange       -> All
   ],
   {i, .1, Pi, Pi/24.}
];


path = FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "moon.gif"}]

Export[
 path, pics, "GIF", 
 "DisplayDurations" -> Append[ConstantArray[1/15., Length[pics] - 1], 1]
]

SystemOpen @ path
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like the process is repeated on the other side as well in the original GIF

Comment: You could consider using the built-in method to generate a picture of the moon: `ColorConvert[Rasterize[GeoGraphics[GeoModel -> Entity["PlanetaryMoon", "Moon"], GeoProjection -> "Orthographic", GeoRange -> All, Background -> Black]], GrayLevel]`

Comment: Haven't played around with it much until the other question about projecting the moon came up. What if you tweak the `ImageSize` option of  `GeoGraphics[]` and the options of `Rasterize[]`?

Comment: @J.M. it does change something but somehow I wasn't able to pick parameters and generate an image that would look nice.

Comment: @PythonMaster Yeah, it is slightly different. I have a problem with motivation once I find solution to the core of the task :P So don't wait for that but I will try to update this post in near future :)

Comment: @Kuba Direct applying `Rasterize` before `Export` is generally a wrong idea, I wrote a [post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94535/280) about this. It is unfortunate that `Rasterize` by default returns `Graphics` instead of `Image`. :(

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks, I didn't know about that. Strange design.

Comment: That is an interesting way to format MMA code! Did you do it by hand?

Comment: @Aisamu Yep, I'm trying to write my packages similarly, way more readable.

Comment: Wow, I was honestly expecting some IDE magic. `ColorFunction -> ("Impressed" &)`

Answer (score 1):

I've always wished the moon was more habitable. Starting from the OPs picture:

```
moon = ColorConvert[
  Import["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Full_\
Moon_as_Seen_From_Denmark.jpg"], "Grayscale"]; 
ReliefPlot[ImageData[moon], ColorFunction -> "GreenBrownTerrain"]
```

[image]

Comment: So that's the fabled danish moon,  eh!